# reading zip file header efficiently in node.js

Tags: node.js, zip

There are various zip modules for node. Generally they seem to follow a pattern like this:

```
// Creating a zipfile object
var zf = new zipfile.ZipFile('./test/data/world_merc.zip');

// the zipfile has a list of names:
// zf.names[0] === 'world_merc.prj'
```

The snippet above was lifted from the `node-zipfile` README here https://github.com/mapbox/node-zipfile, but for example a similar example exists for the `AdmZip` package: https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip.

So this struck me as odd, because it appears both of these libraries assume synchronous code (at the very least, you need to open the file to read the header, which is blocking, right)?

So I dug into the implementation of `AdmZip` and it turns out you can pass a buffer to the `AdmZip` constructor, e.g. you can do this:

```
fs.readFile('./my_file.zip', function(err, buffer) {
    var zip = new AdmZip(buffer);
    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); 
});
```

But that's only marginally better, because it appears `AdmZip` expects that I want to read the whole file in just to access the header. I read the zip spec and my understanding is that the file "central directory file header" which lists the contents is at the end of the file anyway.

So that was a super long lead in to the question, does there exist a node library which will efficiently and asynchronously read the zip contents (e.g. not realize the entire zip file in memory if all I'm going to do is look at the central directory header)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I found a suitable implementation that efficiently reads the header async:

https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip